# Docker: Jenkins-jdk11 fails to connect to Nexus due to JAXB-API has not been found

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, nexus

Get the following error while trying to connect `jenkins-jdk11` to `nexus3` containers running same network in docker-compose on JDK8 based host system. Afer clicking "Test Connection"
[image]

The error:

```
Nexus Repository Manager 3.x connection failed
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.zz.ex.a(SourceFile:33)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.zz.ex.b(SourceFile:24)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.zz.ez.handleResponse(SourceFile:54)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:223)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:165)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.zz.et.a(SourceFile:84)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.zz.es.getVersion(SourceFile:126)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.repository.v3.RepositoryManagerV3Client$getVersion.call(Unknown Source)
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  jenkins-jdk11:
    user: root
    image: 'jenkins/jenkins:jdk11'
    ports:
      - '10000:8080'
      - '50000:50000'
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Warsaw
      - "JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory"
    links:
      - nexus3
    volumes:
      - 'jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
         condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - backend
  nexus3:
    container_name: nexus3
    image: 'sonatype/nexus3'
    ports:
      - '50001:8081'
    volumes:
      - 'local-nexus-data-volume:/nexus-data'
    networks:
      - backend
volumes:
  jenkins-data:
    driver: local
  local-nexus-data-volume:
    driver: local
networks:
  backend:
    driver: overlay
```

**What seems to be the problem and how to successfully connect to Nexus?**

EDIT
My JAXB plugin installed:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue listed on Jenkins wiki for Jenkins compatability issues with Java 11. Here is the [link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JAXB+usage+in+Jenkins+plugins).

One possible solution is to add `-Djavax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory` in the JAVA_OPTS while running Jenkins. You can do this by passing env variables to container using `--env` option :

```
--env JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

Or in docker compose using `environment` :

```
services:
  jenkins:
    image: 'jenkins/jenkins:jdk11'
    environment:
     - JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

Comment: I have updated the question with docker-compose.yml  the change from your suggestion but still same error.

Comment: Yes I use swarm. I use 'overlay' because I read it is required for swarm.  Jenkins and nexus use same machine. When I put `IP:8081` in "Server URL" in Nexus config at Jenkins it freezes at on saying "Testing..." ,  and nothing happenes.

Comment: I have added the screenshot from plugins with version but it seems to be already installed , however with possibility to downgrade.

Comment: I did that also in my first try. Still freeze on "Testing..."

Comment: But you do not receive exception about ClassPath error anymore? What port are you using now as your nexus service port ? 50001?

Comment: If you do not receive the classpath error any more - setting up the property solved your problem, but there has to be something wrong with your swarm configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the conflict of java version been used by Jenkins & nexus make sure to set the Java environment as same as java -version as same below

java -version
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)

cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"

JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"

#JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"

this solved for me after going with this requirement